# Should one leave asserts in production iOS apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, assert

Common practice might be to put asserts in code to check input parameters, data integrity, and such, during app development.

I test my apps, BUT, given that I'm not Knuth (and **he** writes $1 checks), and I can't afford to employ a large team of full-time QA people as do some medical and space systems software companies, I assume that all my apps will always have plenty of bugs that have never yet been seen during testing or QA.  Assuming otherwise seems quite intellectually dishonest.  So after testing an app (and obviously removing all bugs causing any previously seen ASSERT failures) and getting the app ready to ship to Apple, what should be done with all the ASSERT checks in the Release/Distribution build?  Leave or no-op?

Here's one rationale for leaving them in:  If an app acts wonky for some users, the app might get rated by those users as 1-Star without anyone ever telling the developer why in sufficient detail.  But if the app crashes from an ASSERT failure, the app might still get rated 1-Star, but the developer could potentially get some crash dumps, indirectly via iTunes and iTunes Connect if enough users opts in, to figure out what is going wrong.  And if the app gets rejected by Apple due to a brand new ASSERT crash, that will prevent a bad version of the app from ever getting onto one's customer's devices.

Comment: Try to beta test a lot. With IPA generation inside XCode and over-the-air installation, distributing your beta to people is easy-breezy.

Comment: This still makes the false assumption that a beta tested app has no bugs or other problems that could be found by asserts.

Comment: Are you really striving to be 100% bug-free? Or just reasonably bug-free? There's a balance.

Comment: I assume that no (non-trivial, full-featured) app is 100% bug free.  However a developer still has to ship.  The question is whether a shipped app should still have some sort of ASSERT safety net for not-yet-found bugs or not.

Comment: The alternative to a safety net, in the circus, is the hard floor on which the performer gets maimed or killed. The question behind the question is: why would you take the asserts out? To avoid crashing or for performance? The former makes no sense (you would crash eventually anyway, or get into an inconsistent state), and the latter is a total non concern in 99% of the cases...

Comment: Your app will not be bug free, even when beta testing a lot. Also you will get bad reports because of crashes too. So having asserts in the production version will only help, when not relying on iTunes connect for crash reports, you will see hardly any in there in a reasonable time. There are a few services out there that can help, e.g. Bugsense, Crittercism (with latest 3.x SDK) and HockeyApp (I am in involved in the latest) or open source QuincyKit.

Comment: @Kerni what does "you will see hardly any in there in a reasonable time" mean?

Comment: iTunes Connect doesn't really give you good crash reporting data. You are lucky if it shows any, and it takes weeks to show something lots of times. I wrote more about it here: http://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2011/5/28/dont-be-afraid-of-crashes.html

Comment: Thanks @Kerni I never saw this because you didn't tag me. Great stuff!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leave them in for exactly the reasons you specify, but also because in certain cases they act as comments (especially where types are concerned in Objective-C). And do not worry about the performance hit unless it becomes a problem or you know you're in a performance critical situation and a particular assert is going to be run hundreds or thousands of times on the main run-loop.

[Can't resist mentioning this article on asserts vs. NSAssert.](http://vgable.com/blog/2008/12/04/nsassert-considered-harmful/)

Personally, I start to remove the ones that I've put in for debugging purposes, but if you use asserts to check data integrity, parameters, resource dependencies and other related things -- arguably, you could throw Exceptions yourself instead, which might be wiser -- then I would leave them in.

**Note:** A further point is that just removing asserts is utterly stupid, since your app will either crash or be in an inconsistent state, both of which are worse than crashing in a way that you can recognize from the crash logs (so leave the asserts in). Replace asserts with `if` statements, on the other hand, could be a good thing.

Comment: +1 totally agree and am using asserts (vs NSAssert) myself in shipped apps - never regretted it.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the author of the blog article you cited says "turning off asserts is another issue entirely. And I’m going to side-step it by claiming the *right answer is to not use asserts in production code.*"

Comment: That was the bad part of the article ;)

Comment: @MestreLion note Justin's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation: You should leave them *ON* by default. I say: "fail hard, fail early" -- and keep your bugfixes at a higher priority than features.

However, choice is also good -- I don't think one size fits all programs. For this reason, I use multiple types of assertions. Some will be live in release, some will not. I write a *lot* of error detection, and I also write a lot of performance critical programs. I can't leave a ton of diagnostics and sanity checks in hot paths of release builds.

Unfortunately, it cannot be an afterthought (unless maybe you are prepared to prioritize quality and testing for an open-ended amount of time). If you think about it, the single/traditional approach also cannot be an afterthought. With either model, it is best decide whether assertions or which assertions will be enabled in release *before* writing your program.

---

So the basic general form of a dual assert model might look like:

```
#include <assert.h>

/*
  MONDebugAssert assertion is active in debug and disabled in release.
  Recommendation: Always define NDEBUG (or not) in your build settings, 
  and nowhere else.
*/
#if defined(NDEBUG)
    #define MONDebugAssert(e) ((void)0)
#else
    #define MONDebugAssert(e) \
        (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert(#e, __FILE__, __LINE__) : (void)0)
#endif

/* MONAssert assertion is active at all times, including release builds. */
#define MONAssert(e) \
       (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert(#e, __FILE__, __LINE__) : (void)0)
```

where `__assert` is the platform assertion handler.

Then in use:

```
MONDebugAssert(0); // << will fail in debug, and not in release.
MONAssert(0); // << will fail in any case
```

Of course, it is easy enough to adapt for your needs, or create variants where `self` is assumed to be in the scope (like `NSAssert`).

Comment: @Yar i literally use separate macros for these assertions. for historical reasons, they contain the word "assert" if dead in release and "abort" or "fail" if live in release. i write a lot of low level code and write a lot of error checking -- there's a bunch of stuff that should not be in the release build.

Comment: That's great. Do you want to share what these look like, or are they too idiosyncratic to be of general utility?

Comment: @Yar yes, my assertion handlers are quite complex. they include custom  messages, backtrace info, and there are several variants -- it's my second line of defense (the first being the compiler). i won't add mine, but i've added a very basic example (which is a derivative of the definitions in `assert.h`). so that could be a starting point. i also like the names i chose for the demo better than the ones in my codebase =p

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! I'll probably replace this comment when I actually try them...

Comment: @Yar i just updated the whole post on review, haha. you're welcome :)

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but if I use the definition for `MONDebugAssert` in place of that for `MONAssert` it works. Otherwise, I get that `__assert` is undefined (though I can see it)... perhaps because I'm on iOS?

Comment: @Yar oh, right. using this approach you can work around this by either a) declare the prototype of `__assert ` or b) add a conditional `#undef NDEBUG`, `#include <assert.h>`, then immediately restore the definition of (or absence of) `NDEBUG` after the `#include`.

Comment: What behavior do I miss if I use the same definition for MON and MONDebug?

Comment: @Yar that was a mistake -- fixed. they can be the same.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Any reason not to use this same approach with and `NSLog` substitute?

Comment: @Yar you're welcome. unanswerable - i don't think `NSLog` et al. belongs in production code. sure, i have implementations for developer-facing and user-facing messages, but that is information which should *not* be eliminated from any particular build/configuration. if one needs to resort to NSLog/printf et al. debugging or something like that, then it's just somebody's personal information (which shouldn't be committed, IMHO).

Comment: Great stuff. BTW, you've got them backwards, maybe? This `#e, __FILE__, __LINE__` works with no funny business. You picked the one that doesn't work (for me). The one that starts with `#e` works even if I use `#include <assert.h>` at the top. Sorry to drag this out.

Comment: @Yar ok. please just substitute your working version if it makes more sense. as mentioned, the illustration above is not a real/tested program. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There always tends to be something better to do in production code then fail an assert, but sometimes the trade off is less cut and dried.

A good time to assert:  when continuing on will destroy user data ("there is a known good save file already, and I've detected damaged data structures, if I write over the good file with what I have I'll destroy it").   Obviously the "best" option is to not damage the data in the first place.   Second best is to detect damaged data during the save and save to a new file (it might be loadable, or maybe what is in it is valuable enough to salvage via heroic means).

Another good time to assert: when you know continuing on will crash (passing NULL to many plain C functions, about to divide by zero...).  The assert will carry more useful information.   Of corse even better is not getting into that state.  Second best is aborting the operation, not the program ("I can't print" is better then "I threw away your unsaved data, and by the way you can't print").

You can pretty much always break things down like that.    However error recovery is pretty complex, and handing some errors will double or worse the size of your code for something that may never happen...and then you have to figure out how to test it, and...

...so it is a trade off.  What else in your program will be better if you skimp on error recovery?   Will it be enough better to make up for the extra crashes?

Answer (score 1):

My `NSAssert` failures indicate something went horribly wrong and proceeding further would result in undefined behaviour and data corruption. I can't imagine why people parrot disabling them in release builds.

If you can recover from it, you should be using an `NSError` instead.