# What's a reliable way to make an iOS app crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to test my app's crash reporting out in the field by deliberately having it crash when the user performs a particular action that a real user is unlikely to do accidentally.

But what's a good reliable way of making the app crash that doesn't create a warning at compile time?

**Edit:** Note that many seemingly obvious answers to this question result in exceptions that get caught by Cocoa and thus don't result in the app crashing.

Comment: I'm getting `WebKit discarded an uncaught exception` for all of these ideas so far! Who knew it was so hard to make an app crash these days?

Comment: I don't think any of these has anything to do with WebKit...

Comment: Yep, open Safari on an iPad 1 and browse to a page with a lot of images. Always works for me. :/

Comment: `(void)0/0;`, `(void)*(char*)0;`

Comment: Be careful with some of the answers here invoking **undefined behavior**. That is actually very nasty advice!

Comment: @usr - By definition, testing is an attempt to invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @usr, very nasty advice because theoretically it might cause the app to do something other than crash? Not really that nasty, is it?

Comment: @Nestor C++ undefined behavior is more complex than that. See http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 Undefined means that the access violation is not guaranteed. Instead the compiler may just delete code arbitrarily for example.

Comment: @HotLicks not at all. Undefined behavior is a C/C++ concept. You *never* want it. See http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213

Answer (score 141, accepted):

in Objective-C use C directly to cause a bad access

```
strcpy(0, "bla");
```

*Note: while this works on any system I know -- in a future version of the C runtime OR the compiler this might not lead to a crash anymore. see [Is null pointer dereference undefined behavior in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651642/is-null-pointer-dereference-defined-behavior-in-objective-c))*

(in swift you would have to bridge to objC to do this)

Comment: this is IMHO the most reliable way

Comment: Ah yes, that gets around the `WebKit discarded an uncaught exception` problem too.

Comment: there was a typo still :D no @"bla" but "bla"

Comment: Apparently (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651642/is-null-pointer-dereference-defined-behavior-in-objective-c), this is undefined behavior and actually a very bad answer! The compiler can legally optimize out both statements and just do nothing. I suggest you delete this answer. It might lead people to actually do this.

Comment: So the compiler can inline the method and determine that the pointer is dereferenced unconditionally. That triggers undefined behavior. This goes for any pure function at all, not just for strcpy. the compiler can always peek inside. Just like a human.

Comment: on ios and osx and windows and redhat it always has crashed so in the given context, i'd say its valid. I will add a disclaimer

Comment: This works perfectly in 2016 with macOS Sierra and Xcode 8 simulators.

Answer (score 98):

My current favourite:

```
assert(! "crashing on purpose to test <insert your reason here>");
```

A classic:

```
kill( getpid(), SIGABRT );
```

And some pr0n:

```
*(long*)0 = 0xB16B00B5;
```

All of them generate crashes captured by my crash reporting tool.

Comment: assert doesn't crash on release versions, that's why it's an assert

Comment: it depends on your build settings; also, I think the question is about testing, it seems ok to keep asserts in test builds

Comment: A lot of people (including me) leave asserts in release builds. There is no reason to disable them.

Comment: @MestreLion Size shouldn't be a problem. Performance maybe in games.

Comment: @Sulthan: `assert()` is a debug feature, makes little sense to leave such cruft in release builds. There are unit tests for that.

Comment: @MestreLion Asserts are not only a debug feature. In the same way you could argument than you shouldn't check parameters and throw IllegalArgumentException in Java. I repeat, there is no reason to remove them. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481396/should-one-leave-asserts-in-production-ios-apps

Comment: IMHO `assert` is not a debug feature. A failed assert is a bug you thought impossible. It's better to abort, even a release build, than keep running a program with unpredictable consequences.

Comment: I agree with this answer, and I think this is the one the OP should have accepted. `assert` means exactly what the OP is asking for: "This should never happen". Leaving an assert working in a release build is not difficult and there's nothing wrong with doing so.

Comment: "This should never happen" is very different from "I cannot recover from this condition", so assert is not always the best case to catch unpredictable errors. There are exceptions for that. Also, asserts don't deal with open files.

Comment: @matt: I don't know the details, but `assert(0)` could conceivably terminate more gracefully than a bad access. To test crash reporting properly, I want something as nasty as a real unforeseen bug.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651642/is-null-pointer-dereference-defined-behavior-in-objective-c. The null dereference is undefined behavior and might do anything at all. Including being optimized out!

Answer (score 27):

Since we all use Clang for iOS, this is fairly reliable:

```
__builtin_trap();
```

This has the benefit that it's designed for exactly this purpose, so it shouldn't generate any compiler warnings or errors.

Answer (score 25):

How about a good old stack overflow :)

```
- (void)stackOverflow
{
    [self stackOverflow];
}
```

Answer (score 24):

`abort();` causes abnormal termination… That is a crash.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/abort.3.html

Answer (score 16):

Most popular one - unrecognised selector crash:

```
NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[object performSelector:@selector(asfd)];
```

Make sure you don't have -asdf method implemented in that class haha

Or index beyond bound exception:

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray array];
[array objectAtIndex:5];
```

And of course
`kill( getpid(), SIGABRT );`

Answer (score 14):

I think in Swift you could easily throw a fatal error:

```
func foo() {
    fatalError("crash!")
}
```

It is actually even intended to use this feature in case something goes wrong in order to make the app crash.

To avoid an if statement in a special case, you could use `precondition`, too. It's similar to  `assert`, makes thus the intention (if wanted) pretty clear and is *not* removed in the final release as `assert`. It is used like `precondition(myBoolean, "This is a helpful error message for debugging.")`.

Answer (score 9):

Send a message to a deallocated object

Comment: This is actually very unreliable. You can still send messages to deallocated objects as long as their memory is not reused. This is the whole reason people have historically had very hard to debug double-release errors. It's only when the memory is reclaimed by another object that sending a message may cause an exception.

Answer (score 7):

You can also raise an exception:

```
[NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
            format:@"I want to test app crashes!."];
```

Comment: I don't think the exception is that good way, catching exception is common so you could accidentally catch it. Catching signals is not so common so bad access or similar things would be more reliable. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
exit(0);
```

(must... type... 30 characters)

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes but in fact this will make the app terminate and return to Springboard, which, although it can be useful in itself, isn't what OP wanted, which is to trigger an untrapped exception

Answer (score 3):

Add a gesture recognizer to a view that recognizes a 10 finger tap (5 fingers for iPhone as 10 can get a bit crowded).  The GR has a method attached to it that executes anyone of the previously mentioned surefire ways to get your app to crash.  Most users are not going to lay 10 fingers down on your app, so you're safe from the general user accidentally causing the crash.

However you should be able to use something like Testflight or just deploying it to personal devices and test in the wild before ever submitting it to Apple.  Having a forced crash could get your app rejected by Apple.

Comment: My Cocos2d app crashes when I do a extreme multi touch, and I've got that as an unresolved bug. I don't have any GR, but I've enabled multitouch in Cocos2d. Do I experience the crash that you describe? You mean that this is expected/wanted behavior?

Comment: @Fredrik I don't think you're crash you are describing is expected (IMO crashes should never be expected and I personally don't think it's a good idea to purposefully put one in your app for that matter).  You could try symbolicating the crash and finding out exactly what method is causing the app to crash.  It could be something inside the Cocos2d framework that's causing the crash when the 'extreme multi touch' occurs.  If that is the case then your best bet is filing a bug with the Cocos2d guys.

Answer (score 2):

could try something like

```
NSArray* crashingArray = [NSArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
[crashingArray release];
```

should crash on an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (might need to release it a second time but normaly it should crash like this already)

Comment: Wont compile with ARC enabled.

Comment: well if ouy use ARC you could also do this : NSArray* crashingArray = [NSArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
[crashingArray objectAtIndex:0];
this should be crashing

Answer (score 1):

I will go with:`int raise(int sig);`

To get more info `>man raise`

Answer (score 0):

I would just kill the process normally:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
```

So if you install a handler with signal you can also handle the crash, finishing to write opened files and these things.

Comment: this is already included in [madmw's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13510862/106435)

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
[self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain why this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When working with RubyMotion I use this:

```
    n=Pointer.new ('c', 1)
    n[1000] ='h'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *array = [NSArray new];
    NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:8]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

a wrong `NSLog` statement will do it

```
NSLog(@"%@",1);
```