# Is null pointer dereference undefined behavior in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, undefined-behavior

In C and C++, null pointer dereference is undefined behavior. What about Objective-C?

In other words, what is this code guaranteed to do?

```
*(long*)0 = 0;
```

Background: I wonder if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13510808/122718) might trigger undefined behavior potentially causing random things like the statement being optimized out or even weirder things.

Of course, I do not endorse doing this. Still, it is important to know the rules of the language.

Comment: Either way, your code should avoid doing this.

Comment: As I understand it, nil is defined as (id)0. Sending a message to nil doesn't do anything—the runtime ignores it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Objective-C is nothing more than an object-oriented layer on top of C, pure C statements don't have special additional meanings. According to this, in this case, `*(long*)0 = 0;` is evaluated and interpreted just like in C (since it *is* C) and thus it invokes undefined behavior. As such, it is not guaranteed to do anything.

Comment: we're talking about the strcpy here.. at least that's the only thing I wrote... can THAT be optimized away?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Now I see - well, undefined behavior is undefined, so nobody can tell what **will** happen for 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing a null pointer remains undefined in Objective-C.

The only caveat is that messaging doesn't require a dereference. Messaging to a null pointer (or `nil` in Objective-C terms) is always explicitly safe and defined to return a further null pointer.

Hence compound messaging, like `[[class alloc] init]`, is always explicitly safe.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that statement is *guaranteed* to do is invoke undefined behavior.

It may be guaranteed to do something specific on a specific platform with a specific compiler.

Comment: Is there anything to say about mainstream Objective-C compilers regarding this? Do they provide additional guarantees?

Comment: @usr: Clang and GCC can both warn about statically detectable null pointer dereferences. They don't assign it any particular meaning, as that would pointlessly violate the language spec.

Answer (score 0):

a strcpy(0, "bla") as seen in that answer has crashed always and I dont see how that can not work - or be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: The compiler can peek inside and detect that the first argument is being dereferenced.

Comment: Additional note: Whenever a human can determine that there will be a null dereference, the compiler can, too.

Comment: sure the compiler can see its 0 but how would it know that the method doesnt handle 0 just fine...

Comment: If the method does handle 0 fine, there would be no crash. So the code is broken either way (either undefined or no crash).

Comment: So the compiler can inline the method and determine that the pointer is dereferenced unconditionally. That triggers undefined behavior. This goes for any pure function at all, not just for strcpy. the compiler can always peek inside. Just like a human.

Comment: ok, if in theory it could then why doesnt it ... always ^^ [disclaimer: I dont care about my answer, Id never use it either but this seems totally wrong to me]

Comment: Who knows? The strangest things happen in the presence of UB. It has even caused security bugs in the linux kernel because the compiler optimized out checks that were relying on UB. Sometimes it just doesn't use that information and emits code like nothing happended. It is not a case that compiler writers care much about because it shouldn't ever happen.

Comment: we are talking about ios in that question. not some theoretical mega compiler ^^ and there it crashes - always, on any os.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20414/discussion-between-daij-djan-and-usr)